# Getting Logon failed for login 'sa' due to trigger execution. in nodejs app using mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, node-mssql

I am trying to connect to a remote database using below code in node js and getting **"Logon failed for login 'sa' due to trigger execution."** error.

```
    // Database connection
    var sql = require('mssql');

    // Change the config settings to match your 
    // SQL Server and database
    var config = {  
        "server": "my database server IP", // 127.0.0.1
        "user": "nodejs",
        "password": "mypassword",
        "database": "mydatabase"
    };

    sql.setDefaultConfig( config );

    sql.execute( {  
            query: "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
        } ).then( function( results ) {
            console.log( results );
        }, function( err ) {
            console.log( "Something bad happened:", err );
        } 
   );
```

The code is not connecting but when I provide my local IP (127.0.0.1), it works just fine.

FYI: my remote database is accessible if I connect it using SQL Server Management Studio.

Driver Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: Sounds like a logon trigger on the remote system to me. Can you see the logon triggers on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I can see but same database is accessed by other asp.net applications also.

Comment: Well that error occurs from a logon trigger. Do a google search for your error message and will find dozens and dozens of hits. As a slight side topic, you REALLY need to stop using sa to login from applications.

Comment: I resolved the error, there was a problem with that trigger only. It was not related with my application. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.